# Symfony3 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO

Tags: symfony

object in entity can't be converted to string , i tried _toString method ect but nothing works
this is my form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('dateDemandeRDV',DateTimeType::class)
        ->add('etatDemandeRDV',TextType::class)
        ->add('lettreLiaison',TextareaType::class)
        ->add('gsm',NumberType::class)
        ->add('emailDemandeRDV',EmailType::class)
        ->add('idPatient',EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:utilisateur',
                'choice_label' => 'id'
        ))
        ->add('idMedecinDemandeur',NumberType::class)
        ->add('idEtablissementDemandeur',NumberType::class)
        ->add('ok',SubmitType::class);
}
```

and the error text is :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO demande_r_d_v
>   (Date_DemandeRDV, Etat_DemandeRDV, Lettre_Liaison, Gsm,
>   Email_DemandeRDV, Id_Patient, Id_Medecin_demandeur,
>   Id_EtablissementDemandeur) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params ["2012-01-01", "saz", "azda", 85245, "adzazd@adzazd.com", {},
>   871, 9665]:
>
> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\utilisateur
>   could not be converted to string

Comment: how does `idPatient` look like, so what does it expect? and please share `AppBundle:utilisateur`

Comment: When you render the form, does anything show up in the "idPatient" drop-down list? Also, how are you handling the submit? Can you show the controller code where you create the `utilisateur` and persist it?